# C++ VS2008 - Strange errors on class template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2008

I am porting a relatively big code from Linux to Windows (Visual Studio 2008, I have to use that).
I completed the porting and it's working, but I had to comment a small piece of code because Visual Studio gave error on that and I couldn't exactly understand why.
So, basically, there is a functor that collects from a std::map all the "items" that satify a certain condition, defined in the following way:

```
/*
 * Map collector
 */
template<class TMap>
class CMapCollector
{
    public:
        typedef typename TMap::value_type tValueType;

        CMapCollector(void)
        { }

        void operator () (const tValueType& rcValue)
        {
            if (CheckCondition(rcValue))
                mCollector.push(rcValue);
        }

        bool NextResult(void) const
        {
            return (!mCollector.empty());
        }

        tValueType GetResult(void)
        {
            if (!NextResult())
                return tValueType();

            tValueType curr_value = mCollector.front();
            mCollector.pop();
            return curr_value;
        }

    private:
        virtual bool CheckCondition(const tValueType& rcValue) const = 0;

        typedef std::queue<tValueType> tCollectorContainer;

        tCollectorContainer mCollector;
};
```

Then, by inheriting from it, some collector classes are defined. 
I wrote a small example that shows the error, in order to extract it from all the other code:

```
/*
 * Some class
 */
class CMyClass
{
    public:
        CMyClass(const int cNum) : mNum(cNum)
        { }

        bool DifferentFrom(const int cFrom) const
        {
            return (Get() != cFrom);
        }

        bool EqualTo(const int cTo) const
        {
            return (Get() == cTo);
        }

    private:
        int Get(void) const
        {
            return mNum;
        }

        int mNum;
};

/* Some map definition */
typedef std::map<int, CMyClass *> tMyMap;

/*
 * Real collectors
 */

class CNoNullCollector : public CMapCollector<tMyMap>
{
    private:
        bool CheckCondition(const tValueType& rcValue) const
        {
            return (rcValue.second->DifferentFrom(0));
        }
};

class CValueCollector : public CMapCollector<tMyMap>
{
    public:
        CValueCollector(const int cValue) : mValue(cValue)
        { }

    private:
        bool CheckCondition(const tValueType& rcValue) const
        {
            return (rcValue.second->EqualTo(mValue));
        }

        int mValue;
};

/*
 * main
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    tMyMap my_map;

    /* Insert some value */
    my_map.insert(std::make_pair(1, new CMyClass(0)));
    my_map.insert(std::make_pair(2, new CMyClass(1)));
    my_map.insert(std::make_pair(3, new CMyClass(2)));
    my_map.insert(std::make_pair(4, new CMyClass(2)));
    my_map.insert(std::make_pair(5, new CMyClass(3)));

    /* Collect values */
    CNoNullCollector collector = std::for_each(my_map.begin(), my_map.end(), CNoNullCollector());
    while (collector.NextResult())
    {
        CNoNullCollector::tValueType curr_result = collector.GetResult();
        /* Do something ... */
    }

    /* Free memory, not written ... */

    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles fine on Linux with g++ (I tried with both g++ 4.2 and 4.9, available on the machine).
I also tried with Visual Studio 2013, and it was fine.
However, compiling it with VS2008 (and also VS2010), it gives errors when it instantiates the class template "CMapCollector".
The errors are in the std::swap function, called from std::pair, at this point ("utility" file, a standard include):

```
template<class _Ty> inline
void swap(_Ty& _Left, _Ty& _Right)
{   // exchange values stored at _Left and _Right
if (&_Left != &_Right)
    {   // different, worth swapping
    _Ty _Tmp = _Left;

    _Left = _Right;     // <-- error C3892: '_Left' : you cannot assign to a variable that is const
    _Right = _Tmp;      // <-- error C3892: '_Right' : you cannot assign to a variable that is const
    }
}
```

This is the complete error message:

```
    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\utility(22) : error C3892: '_Left' : you cannot assign to a variable that is const
        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\utility(31) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::swap<_Ty>(_Ty &,_Ty &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=int
        ]
        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\utility(64) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Swap_adl<_Ty1>(_Ty &,_Ty &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty1=int,
            _Ty=int
        ]
        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\utility(61) : while compiling class template member function 'void std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::swap(std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)'
        with
        [
            _Ty1=const int,
            _Ty2=CMyClass *
        ]
        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\deque(518) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty1=const int,
            _Ty2=CMyClass *
        ]
        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\queue(24) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::deque<_Ty>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=std::pair<const int,CMyClass *>
        ]
        c:\users\my_name\desktop\test\test\test.cpp(42) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::queue<_Ty>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=std::pair<const int,CMyClass *>
        ]
        c:\users\my_name\desktop\test\test\test.cpp(81) : see reference to class template instantiation 'CMapCollector<TMap>' being compiled
        with
        [
            TMap=tMyMap
        ]
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\utility(23) : error C3892: '_Right' : you cannot assign to a variable that is const
```

If I comment the part in which the class template is instantiated:

```
CNoNullCollector collector = std::for_each(my_map.begin(), my_map.end(), CNoNullCollector());
while (collector.NextResult())
{
    CNoNullCollector::tValueType curr_result = collector.GetResult();
    /* Do something ... */
}
```

the compilation will be successfully completed.
I understand there is some problem with the constantness, but I don't understand where. Why does g++ successfully compile it?

EDIT:

I understood that it's something related to the std::queue and the "key" of the std::map (and therefore the "first" of the std::pair) that is constant by definition, but I didn't figure out how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved by using a queue of constant pointers, so I just store the pointer to the std::pair and not the value of the std::pair itself, which makes also more sense:

```
std::queue<const tValueType *>
```

So the final map collector class becomes:

```
/*
 * Map collector
 */
template<class TMap>
class CMapCollector
{
    public:
        typedef typename TMap::value_type tValueType;

        CMapCollector(void)
        { }

        void operator () (const tValueType& rcValue)
        {
            if (CheckCondition(rcValue))
                mCollector.push(&rcValue);
        }

        bool NextResult(void) const
        {
            return (!mCollector.empty());
        }

        const tValueType *GetResult(void)
        {
            if (!NextResult())
                return NULL;

            const tValueType *curr_value = mCollector.front();
            mCollector.pop();
            return curr_value;
        }

    private:
        virtual bool CheckCondition(const tValueType& rcValue) const = 0;

        typedef std::queue<const tValueType *> tCollectorContainer;

        tCollectorContainer mCollector;
};
```

This compiles fine also with VS2008